# Django floatformat formatting 113.999 to 114.0

Tags: django, django-templates, rounding

I have a value that I'm passing to a template which is 113.999.

When I do `{{ value|floatformat:"-1" }}` it outputs 114.0.

View code:
`some_var = 113.999`

Template code:
`{{ some_var|floatformat }}`

My understanding of floatformat was that it should round, and then not display the decimal part if it was all zeroes.

Is floatformat wrong, or am I?

Comment: What's the Django and Python version, can you give a reproducable example?

Comment: Also, is it possible your view is passing 114 to the template? Can you give the view code as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting, by exploring the code, I've found that the quantizing happens after [the checking of integer](https://github.com/django/django/blame/master/django/template/defaultfilters.py#L163). Thus `113.999` is quantized after it is checked against integer and failed.

IMO, well I'm not an expert of number notation :), `114.0` here represents a rounded-up value and it's not an originally `114`.

If you really don't want this behavior, a quick and awkward way is
 `{{ value|floatformat|floatformat }}`...

Furthermore, `floatformat` uses `-1` by default, thus `{{ value|floatformat }}` is enough in your code.

Comment: This is good - I've concluded the same. +1 for the double floatformat hack.  This will work well for occasional use.  However, we're going to re-write the filter for our purposes as we're going to use it a lot.